Ubuntu 24.04 Wi-Fi connection fails
I am new to Ubuntu. I was a programmer for 30 years so am familiar with most terminology, even though I retired 15 years ago.
USB WiFi found (Netgear WG111v2)
WiFi Services found - Verizon RC400-L Hotspot device
Select the RC400-L
Unable to enter the settings for the device and set the password

It keeps sending me back to the menu with the Network menu item selected, and reloads the Wi-Fi which has the same options as before.

I am not an expert,
I think that you don't have the permission to edit the Network settings.
Thus you should try to change it from the Settings after using the Admin\root password.
